# Get multiple lists/data from MySQL StoredProcedure

Tags: python, mysql, stored-procedures

I'm working in `python` with MySQL and want to get multiple lists of data from Stored Procedure.

i am using `PyMySql` to connect with my Database. And trying to do something like this but its not working

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `spGetData`(IN ssscreenId INT(11),)
BEGIN
    SELECT clientId, clientName FROM apl_cb.Client WHERE isActive = 1 AND isDeleted = 0;

    SELECT bankId, bankName, bankAddress FROM apl_cb.Bank WHERE isDeleted = 0 AND isActive = 1;

    SELECT eventId, eventName, eventGroup FROM  apl_cb.Event WHERE isActive = 1 AND isDeleted = 0 AND menuEvent = 0 AND screenId = ssscreenId;

END
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

thanks

Comment: why all these complications? Why not just execute three queries in python???

Comment: I don't want to execute quires again and again to create the result. By doing this i can save query execution time!

Comment: how are you trying to get your result in python?

Comment: Wether you do it in the stored procedure or with in the python code, you are executing 3 queries. There is absolutely no difference.

Comment: Have you tried using the `nextset()` method on your Python cursor to jump to the next result set? (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#nextset)  If you have tried it, and it doesn't work, then you're out of luck; your Python program won't be able to retrieve multiple resultsets from a single stored procedure.  (But, keep in mind that MySQL stored procedures offer *encapsulation* advantages but not *efficiency* advantages. That is @e4c5's point.)

Comment: I was simply trying fetchall() to retrieve the data! @Null Pointer

Comment: then you should try @O.Jones suggestion. you must be forgetting `nextset()`

Comment: can you provide any reference link, that can justify that "MySQL stored procedures offer encapsulation advantages but not efficiency advantages" . @O. Jones. it will be very helpful to me. thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried using the **nextset()** method on my Python cursor to jump to the next result set and it resolved my problem. thanks a lot @O. Jones. Please answer this so that i can up vote it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using the `nextset()` method on your Python `cursor` to jump to the next result set? (python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#nextset)

If you have tried it, and it doesn't work, then you're out of luck; your Python program won't be able to retrieve multiple resultsets from a single stored procedure.

Keep in mind that MySQL stored procedures offer encapsulation advantages but not efficiency advantages.  The time taken to issue three queries inside a stored procedure is the same as (or maybe a tiny bit higher than) the time of issuing them one after another from your Python program.  Here's an explanation of part of that. http://www.joinfu.com/2010/05/mysql-stored-procedures-aint-all-that/

Comment: Definitely great article on my sql store procedures. But it is 7 years old, and still at that time few people commented that few things has been changed/updated that auther described in blog post. Can you please provide some latest information on this.